# Intuition for average slope

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In this graph (drawn using Mic Paint, any suggestions for better graphing software welcome)
the average slope is the `change in y / change in x = 3/1`

[image]

This is first time I've encountered average slope. What makes average slope different from average of sum of values ? What is the intuition behind the formula for average slope : `change in y / change in x` ?

Comment: You aren't taking an average of anything so I don't see how this is "average slope". $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ *is* the slope of a line connecting the points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2),$ where $\Delta x = x_2 - x_1$ and $\Delta y = y_2 - y_1.$ The intuition is that the line has constant slope and if one travels from the $x$ value of $x_1$ to the $x$ value of $x_2,$ it must necessarily hold that the $y$ values traveled from $y_1$ to $y_2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the hypotenuse of your triangle is $3$ as you say.  Straight lines have constant slope, so if you extend the hypotenuse and measure the slope over any part of the line you will again get $3$.  Now imagine replacing the hypotenuse with a squiggly curve that goes through the same endpoints.  The slope of any part of the curve may be different from $3$, but we define the average as you say.